# Cantor Set and Base 3 Decimal Expansions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, decimal-expansion

I'm trying to show that every point in the Cantor Set (obtained by "middle-thirds" removal, starting with $[0,1]$) has a base 3 decimal expansion consisting of only zeros and twos. I think the proof would be by strong induction, but I'm not sure where to start.

Also, is the converse true? That is, is it true that *every* number of the form $0.a_0a_1a_2...$ (in base 3) with each $a_i$ being $0$ or $2$ is an element of the Cantor Set? I tried constructing a counterexample but haven't had any luck and I'm beginning to think it's true. The question is, how would one prove this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that the word "decimal" means base ten. You want to say just  base 3 expansion".

Comment: I'd really like for there to be a word for "base 3 expansion".  Trinimal? "What's the second digit after the trinimal point?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cantor set in base 3.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610925/cantor-set-in-base-3)

Comment: [Trinary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system) @Andrea

Answer (score 0):

You can get close to both directions in one blow by proving that the intervals you *remove* in step $n$ of the construction of the the Cantor set are exactly those numbers whose base-3 expansion has its *first* `1` at position $n$ after the point.

(A number that has two base-3 expansion will be removed in step $n$ if *both* expansions have their first `1` at position $n$).

From this you can conclude that (a) any number that has an expansion consisting only of `0` and `2` cannot be removed, and (b) any number that *doesn't* have such an expansion *will* be removed in one of the stages.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a $1$ in the 3-expansion. So, one of two things, the other digits are all $2$s until infinity ( $0,...122222...$) and in this case, another 3-expansion is $0,...2$ which corresponds to a point of $\mathbb K_3$, the Cantor set; or the point does not belong to $\mathbb K_3$.

What OP calls "the converse" is obviously true.