# Cantor Set : how did his base 3 system work?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cantor-set, ternary-expansion

I'm reading about [Cantor Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) on Wikipedia.  The article claims Cantor used a base 3 system for his theory, however I'm unable to find any material detailing how this system works.  Can anyone point me to the description of this system and/or describe it here?

I ask because I found the following Egyptian Hieroglyph which appears to represent the picture of his theory.  Unfortunately, the top is a bit clipped, but you can see the general idea of removing thirds.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean “his base three system”? As is detailed in the Wikipedia article(s), the Cantor set is constructed by removing middle-third integrals or by equivalently taking a certain subset of numbers which a certain ternary (base three) expansion

Comment: Try this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610925/cantor-set-in-base-3?rq=1

Comment: You can find a detailed account in the book by Sheldon Axler on Measure Theory. It is freely available here: https://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf It starts on page 55 in the book.

Comment: I can't see that wikipedia claims that "Cantor used a base 3 system for his theory". Of course the ternary system is very useful to study the Cantor set, but the original geometric construction is not based on the ternary system.

Comment: It's no big deal to express the real numbers in decimal in any base.  If you express the decimals in base three then the middle third of $[0,1]$ is $(0.1,0.2)$ and removing to will remove all numbers whose first decimal digit is $1$ (except of $0.1$ itself which can be written as $0.022222.....$).   So the Cantor set is essentially all real number between $0$ and $1$ that do not require the digit $1$.  But Cantor never "used" this that I know of.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415018/ternary-representation-of-cantor-set gives more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In ternary,  the Cantor set consists in all expressions $\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac {a_n}{3^{n+1}}$, where $a_n\in\{0,2\}$.

The requirement that $a_n\ne1$ is equivalent to removing all the middle thirds.

Comment: " (We have to exclude an infinite string of 2's at the end, since that's equivalent to having a 1.)" That's incorrect.  We *must* include infinite 2s at the end as that is our way of including $0.1 = \frac 13$ or $0.21 = \frac 23 + \frac 19$.  Those "endpoints" *must* be included.  (We could say the cantor set is the decimals which either have no $1$ *or* which have only one terminating $1$.  But infinite $2$ allow us to say the simpler "no $1$s.  Period." )

Comment: @fleablood my mistake.   I knew that seemed more complicated than it had to be.